# Parsing get request arguments on the server side in Python

Tags: python, python-requests, get

I have a Python script hosted on a cloud server, and I have an API which is used to execute this script. The API and method to execute this script are given below:

```
import requests
url = "https://base-adress/api/id/run?param1={param1}&param2={param2}"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

And now I want to parse these arguments passed in a [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods) request inside the Python script that is hosted on the cloud server. How can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

To parse the arguments passed in the GET request inside the Python script hosted on your cloud server, you can use a web framework like Flask or Django, which makes it easier to handle incoming requests and their parameters. Here's an example using Flask:

1. Install Flask (if you haven't already) by running: `pip install Flask`
2. Create a Flask app and handle the GET request parameters:

```py
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/id/run', methods=['GET'])
def execute_script():
    # Get query parameters from the request
    param1 = request.args.get('param1')
    param2 = request.args.get('param2')
    
    # Here, you can execute your script using the received parameters
    # Replace this with your actual script logic
    result = f"Executing script with param1: {param1} and param2: {param2}"
    
    return jsonify({"result": result})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)  # Run the app on your cloud server's IP and port
```

3. Run the Flask app on your cloud server. This will listen for incoming requests on the specified IP and port (e.g., http://your_server_ip:5000).
4. Your modified API call in your script can remain the same:

```py
import requests

base_url = "http://your_server_ip:5000"  # Update this with your server's IP and port
url = f"{base_url}/api/id/run"
params = {"param1": "value1", "param2": "value2"}
response = requests.get(url, params=params)

print(response.json())
```

Remember to replace `"value1"` and `"value2"` with the actual values you want to pass as parameters. When you make the API call, the Flask app will receive the parameters, execute the script logic, and return the result.

Make sure your cloud server's firewall and networking configurations allow incoming connections on the specified port (in this example, port 5000) if you choose to use a different port.